# SUID bit disappearing from a program

Tags: systemd, suid

I maintain a bunch of Debian 11.8 servers and recently something weird has started happening. The SUID bit has started disappearing from a program on all servers roughly at the same time.

For example, two days ago `/usr/lib/qemu/qemu-bridge-helper` lost the SUID bit on 4 servers roughly at the same time. Then yesterday the SUID bit disappeared on 2 more servers.

On all servers the following happened:

```
[Sun Oct  8 06:33:57 2023] systemd[1]: systemd 247.3-7+deb11u4 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPAR
MOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +ZSTD +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN
 +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=unified)
[Sun Oct  8 06:33:57 2023] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[Sun Oct  8 06:33:57 2023] systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service:11: Support for option SysVStartPriority= ha
s been removed and it is ignored
[Sun Oct  8 06:33:57 2023] systemd-journald[392]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd).
[Sun Oct  8 06:33:57 2023] systemd[1]: Stopping Journal Service...
[Sun Oct  8 06:33:57 2023] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Succeeded.
[Sun Oct  8 06:33:57 2023] systemd[1]: Stopped Journal Service.
[Sun Oct  8 06:33:57 2023] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Consumed 5min 10.083s CPU time.
[Sun Oct  8 06:33:57 2023] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[Sun Oct  8 06:33:57 2023] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[Sun Oct  8 06:33:57 2023] systemd-journald[4157624]: Received client request to flush runtime journal.
```

After this dmesg entry the program `/usr/lib/qemu/qemu-bridge-helper` lost the SUID bit.

Does anyone know what could have happened? Did systemd do it? Does it have some kind of security measure that scans the system and removes the SUID bit from programs?

Right now I solved it by putting `chmod u+s /usr/lib/qemu/qemu-bridge-helper` into cron job that runs every minute so that when it happens, I put the SUID bit back.

Comment: Limiting SUID is a common security benchmark. DISA STIG, CIS, etc. Do you have any security baseline tools running in your environment? Something that could be enforcing policy? Any remote logins shortly before it was changed? (In particular, from a service account or security auditor.)

Answer (score 1):

If manually applying the permissions temprarily resolves the issue then you can rule out a nosuid mount option.

The first thing I would be checking is whether there was any deployment / patching happenning to the host at the time (`dpkg -S /usr/lib/qemu/qemu-bridge-helper` will tell you which package it came in and /var/log/dpkg should list any changes).

Other than monitoring the file with auditctl, I don't know of a way to get the exact time a file's permissions were changed. Enabling audit on the affected files will capture any future occurrences. Knowing that time would be useful for reconciling this event with other things going on (logins, cron jobs). As @AaronCopley says, over-zealous/under-competent ITSecurity could be a cause.

> On all servers the following happened

That looks like startup messages. But you have the problem on physical hosts? That would lend some weight to the update theory - but odd that you didn't mention the reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "audit" system to detect what process may be changing the permissions:

```
auditctl -w /usr/lib/qemu/qemu-bridge-helper -p wa
```

> Does it have some kind of security measure that scans the system and removes the SUID bit from programs?

It doesn't.

> ```
> [Sun Oct  8 06:33:57 2023] systemd[1]: systemd 247.3-7+deb11u4 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +ZSTD +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=unified)
> [Sun Oct  8 06:33:57 2023] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
> ```

This looks a bit like `systemctl daemon-reexec` (aka `telinit u`) done as part of a package upgrade, perhaps during Debian's regular unattended-upgrades run or some other kind of cronjob.